# SQL Select First Two Characters Of Postcodes

Tags: sql, where-clause, wildcard, sql-like

I need to select the first two characters of a post code which I can do.
E.G "BW" "CW" Etc.

But when I need to select some post codes that have a number after the first letter e.g "B1,B2,B3,B4"   how would I do this?

I think I need a wildcard for numeric values only so it will only show the "B1,B2" and not "BW,BT" etc.

Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Post the sample data and sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you can do this:

```
WHERE postcode LIKE '[A-Z][0-9]%'
```

That would match postcodes beginning with `B1` or `B2`, etc. and not match postcodes starting with `BW` or `BT`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In most databases, you would use `left()`:

```
select left(postcode, 2)
```

Some require the use of `substr()`:

```
select substr(postcode, 1, 2)
```

Then, to get the number, you can add:

```
where substr(postcode, 2, 1) between '0' and '9'
```

or:

```
where substring(postcode, 2, 1) between '0' and '9'
```